# How to Avoid Repeating a Subject

Tags: ellipsis, subjects, coordination, conjunction-reduction

**Question:** Is sentence 2 correct? or

Can I remove 2nd and 3rd **he** in sentence 1?

---

*Sentence 1:* When Jack saw me, **he** came over to me, **he** shook hands,...

*Sentence 2:* When Jack saw me, came over to me, shook hands,...

Comment: Not sure why Mr Chasi deleted the answer.  It's actually correct.  When the repeating element is removed, it's referred to as "ellipsis".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write:

> When Jack saw me, **he** came over to me and shook hands,...

I would leave the first "he" in, because there are separate actions (*saw me* vs. *came over to me*).

Also you could leave out "to me" as it is also repetitive and already understood in context.

> When Jack saw me, **he** came over and shook hands,...